# Extending the support for Writeable Image Formats in Java?

Tags: java, image, format

I would like to create a version of the same image in multiple formats (the more the better). ImageIO supports only few and the plugins available often only support read but no write.

Writing own implementations is off-limit. I think about even using command line tools but I would prefer another solution if available since command line tools are not portable.

Any ideas? Anyone solved the same problem alread?

Comment: If you don't want to write your own implementations or use command line tools, then your only option is to find a(nother) library that provides the functionality.

Comment: ImageMagick would be something that would be available and portable (at least to the platforms we use) but I would prefer a Java only solution.

Comment: Then you're looking in the wrong place. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." In your place I'd be spending time at Google, not at SO.